# Error : Attribute validationgroup not allowed on element button at this point

Tags: asp.net, w3c-validation

I recently test my website on validator.w3.org for html validate elements and I found one error and it's.

> **Error: Attribute validationgroup not allowed on element button at this point. From line 306, column 21; to line 306, column 329**

it's the code:

```
 <button onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate('ordernow');
__doPostBack('Price_Calculator_New2_12may2016$CalculateButto‌​nSubmit','')" id="Price_Calculator_New2_12may2016_CalculateButtonSubmit" class="btn btn-large cal_btn class47" type="button" ValidationGroup="ordernow">
```

and my website url is : projectsdeal.co.uk

I tried to find this line of code I think it's come from any script. My website is on `ASP.Net` platform.